# How to go between partitions in terminal

Tags: command-line, partitioning

A very basic query which requires your kind guidance. If I am at command prompt in either DOS or Windows, I would use, (if I am in C: drive) `d:` to go to drive D. What is the equivalent in Ubuntu Terminal if I want to move around between partitions, from sda1 to sda2 for example?

Answer (score 16):

Ok, this is one of the fundamental differences between windows and linux. The Windows file system uses devices as starting points for each section of the file system. So you have:

```
c:\  
d:\
e:\
```

Linux/Unix systems use the concept of a unified file system. **Everything** is under the root folder, and can be arbitrarily mixed together. The user and programs do not know about devices because they have been abstracted away. So, all linux systems will have the same [general hierarchy](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/).

A linux system will look something like this:

```
/
|---var
|---lib
|---home
|---mnt
```

But these folder could be on the same hard drive, or separate hard drives. They can even be network folders! There is a special folder called /dev for if a program actually needs to talk to the physical device. So, anywhere that you want to go on a linux system will *never* require switching devices like on windows.

However, sometimes a device is not added to the filesytem! It will be plugged in, the OS can see it as a device, but it has not been *mounted*. Modern linux systems will try and do this for you as necessary. Sometimes it doesn't work, and you have to do it your self.  That is what the [mount](http://ss64.com/bash/mount.html) command is for. It is also the original purpose of the /mnt folder, so you can have an obvious place to mount new sections of the file system.

Before mounting a drive:

```
|---mnt
    |---temp
```

After mounting drive to /mnt/temp:

```
|---mnt
    |---temp
        |---docs
        |---programs
        |---tmp
        |---extra
        |---backups
        |---other stuff
```

So you can mount a drive, then use `cd` to move into it, or anywhere else in the file system. This allows for neat things, like having your `/home` directory on a separate hard drive, in case you want to switch linux distros later, or so you can back it up. The /tmp folder is often not on an actual device at all! It's could be some ram treated as a folder. That makes it easy to put stuff there, then have it cleaned up when you reboot.

Comment: the best answer!

Answer (score 12):

Partitions that are mounted are found in the filesystem. They are usually mounted to the folders `/mnt/` or `/media/`.

type `df` in the terminal to display all mounted partitions and where they are mounted . You can also use the **Disk Utility** application to see where each partition is mounted.

then *cd* into your partition using. For example if the partition mount is called *data*:

`cd /media/data`

Comment: @Achu. As far as I understand it `/dev/` contains device files for all devices but the mount points are generally `/media/` for removable media and `/mnt/` for manual mounts.

Comment: um, just a small comment: windows partition isn't mounted by default. There's only `cdrom/` in 'mnt/'

Answer (score 6):

This is my process. Adapt the numbers as needed

1. execute `lsblk` first.

> ```
>  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>     sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
>     ├─sda1   8:1    0   1.5G  0 part 
>     ├─sda2   8:2    0 138.6G  0 part 
>     ├─sda3   8:3    0   8.1G  0 part 
>     ├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
>     ├─sda5   8:5    0  68.5G  0 part /
>     └─sda6   8:6    0   5.8G  0 part 
>     sdb      8:16   0  14.9G  0 disk 
>     └─sdb1   8:17   0  14.9G  0 part /media/SergKolo/SERG
>     sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
> ```

2. Identify which partition is what, e.g, by size, i know /dev/sda2 is my Windows 7 partition.
3. execute `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/SergKolo/`
4. If step 3 successful , you now have folder in `/media/SergKolo` which will correspond to windows partition. Navigate there and enjoy

Comment: If you like this answer, rate, comment and subscripe ! Oh, wait, wrong site ^_^ But simple upvote will do,too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the way I use to go to other partition where I have saved all my data...

```
   cd ..
```

This goes to the previous directory.

After this, I am on the home folder, so I execute once again `cd ..` to go to the / directory, once I'm here I execute

```
cd media
```

Here you have all your mounted partitions, just execute:

```
ls
```

and choose which partition you want to get in, and:

```
cd partitionYouChoose
```

you may see here the name of a partition with many characteres like 997ac596-09ce-453b-8ccd-2120839ba825 or something like that.

I hope to help you.

Comment: Your first command is invalid since it has an open backquote with no command and no end backquote.  It does not take you to your home directory.  To do that it is simply `cd` with no arguments.  From there `cd ..` takes you to /home, not /.  If your goal is to get to /media, then you can skip all of that rigamarole and just `cd /media`.

Comment: Just a suggestion to improve your answer: the partition actually has to be mounted in order to navigate to `/media` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how you do it.

Log into ssh as the root user.

You'll see this:

```
root@yourserver [~]#
```

Ok so if you saw that `[~]` then you are root. But it also means /root.
In other words, `[~]` = `[/root]`. †

Now to get to the other partitions, such as a second hard drive, first you need to find out what partitions you have. Find this by putting `lsblk`

```
root@yourserver [~]# lsblk
```

For me, it game something like this:

```
sda                  8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0   250M  0 part /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0 931.3G  0 part
  ├─vg-root (dm-0) 253:0    0 915.5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg-swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  11.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg-tmp (dm-2)  253:2    0     4G  0 lvm  /tmp
sdb                  8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1               8:33   0 931.5G  0 part /mnt/home2
```

Ok, so here in this setup which I simplified above, all you need to be concerned about is the `sdb1` which is the second partition (I have more drives but I removed them from the output above for this answer).

For me, `sdb` is a second hard drive, but you can do the same thing if `sdb` is a second partition. It essentially functions the same.

Next, you need to get out of the root folder. Do this by doing the following:

```
root@yourserver [~]# ../
```

Now you will be here:

```
root@yourserver [/]#
```

Notice that `[~]` became `[/]`

Next, you need to enter your mounts folder. You can know what this is because if you look at the `lsblk` above, you can see at the bottom left that `sdb1` is located in the `/mnt/` folder. This folder might be different for you. If so just put whatever name is there.

Finally you are ready to enter the new hard drive or new partition. `cd` enters a folder.

```
root@yourserver [/]# cd mnt
```

Now you are here:

```
root@yourserver [/mnt]#
```

Make sure you're in the right place. Enter the following:

```
root@yourserver [/mnt]# ls
```

Now your output might look like this.

```
./  ../  home2/  secondary/
```

If you see the directory on the new drive or partition, you're in! Now just `cd` to the right place. Example *(`-lh` flag means human readable)*:

```
root@yourserver [/mnt]# cd home2
```

Great! Now you're rolling! Now you can display the contents of your desired folder like this:

```
root@yourserver [/mnt/home2]# ls -lh
```

You might get an output like this:

```
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x   5 root      root      4.0K Mar 12 14:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root      root      4.0K Mar 12 14:00 ../
drwx------   2 root      root       16K Mar 12 13:58 lost+found/
drwx--x--x  12 myfolder1 myfolder1 4.0K Mar 12 11:33 myfolder1/
drwx------  11 root      root      4.0K Mar 12 14:09 myfolder2/
```

Okay, I think that covers the scope of this question, you can take it from there! Good luck! :)

† ***Side note:*** (proof of this is to `[~]# cd ../` and then `[/]# cd root` and now you are back in `[~]#`)

***Debug info:***
*These instructions were written for a CentOS 6.5 system which is using cPanel/WHM and has a second hard drive.*